# VMWare: File system is critically low on free space and VMWARE Player paused because disk is too full

Tags: vmware, disk-usage, vmware-player, free

I'm receiving this error message when I start up my VMWare Player. I think I have enough free space - would appreciate help as important files are on this machine!

> The file system upon which '/home/tacchino/vmware/Windows 10 x64'
> resides is critically low on free space. Allowing this virtual machine
> to continue may cause it to fail unexpectedly. VMware Player has
> paused this virtual machine because the disk on which the virtual
> machine is stored is almost full. To continue, free an additional 12.4
> GB of disk space.

[image: 1]
[image: df -h output]
[image: VMWARE Settings]

Comment: Can you check the free space in the partition of the disk that is mounted as home?  `df -h` would work

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for your reply - screenshot of df -h output is in the main body of the post

Comment: Please note that you seem to have a single partition `/dev/nvme0b1p1`, and that this disk has only 52 gB free.  Should your VM attempt to grow to it's mazimum size, it would need to consume 70 gB.  Do you have additional storage available somewhere?

Comment: @CharlesGreen - thanks again.  I was able to increase the partition to have 87G available (60% used) by doing some file clean up / transferring files to an external hard drive.  VM now starting, but seems slow.   Should I try and reduce disk usage further? Not sure how really. I do have a SSD. '

Comment: @CharlesGreen - is another option to just restart with a new vm and get rid of this one? I transferred all important files so can stat fresh if that's best.  Or could you help me with #2? I'm not highly technical.

Comment: It may help - I don't depend upon my VM Windows machine for much, and I have found this it's happy with a 60 GB disk.  If you can allocate more ram to the VM, that will help it's performance as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition that your virtual machine is stored in `/dev/nvme0n1p2` has 52GB of free space left.  The VMDK file storing your VM is currently 69GB, but can grow by another 70GB.  It must be assumed that this is a sparse disk image, and that it will enlarge itself as required.  It will however currently grow past the physical size that you have available for it.

Potential solutions would include:

1. Adding disk space to your physical machine - this would involve adding another SSD or HDD to your machine to allow for a larger VM to be run
2. Reducing the maximum size that the VM disk is allowed to consume.  As a Windows device, you would need to first shrink the partition within Windows, and then use VMWare tools to shrink the disk image file.  You may require a temporary disk, such as a USB disk, to allow for additional storage while shrinking the VMDK file.

---

On the perceived speed of the disk:  Neither the ext4 file system or the SSD work well when close to full.